# HAProxy Secure Renegotiation

Tags: ssl, haproxy

I have configured our HAProxy server to terminate TLS/SSL and have my ciphers setup. Everything is working - however I get an A- from SSL Labs: https://ssllabs.com/ssltest/ due to not having support for secure negotiation. The message from SSL labs is:

There is no support for secure renegotiation. Grade reduced to A-.  MORE INFO »

I would like our customers to see an A as our grade. I have scanned the haproxy documentation and can't find anything about secure renegotiation support. Is this not supported by haproxy?

I have this as my global haproxy config:

```
global
  log /dev/log  local0
  log /dev/log  local1 notice
  chroot /var/lib/haproxy
  stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
  stats timeout 30s
  user haproxy
  group haproxy
  daemon
  # Default SSL material locations
  ca-base /usr/local/etc/haproxy/certs/
  ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP
  ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3 no-tlsv10 no-tlsv11
```

And the frontend:

```
frontend https
  bind 0.0.0.0:443 ssl crt /usr/local/etc/haproxy/chain.pem ca-ignore-err all
  mode http
  maxconn 400
  acl jbossun path_beg /path1 OR /path2
  #insert stickiness here
  use_backend prod-jboss if jbossun
  default_backend prod-default
```

But I do not know what else to add to make it do secure renegotiation. Does anyone know what flag is needed? Or what I need to add?

Comment: please provide you haproxy conf

Comment: added, thanks. I do not know if I need to add something else to allow secure renegotiation?

Comment: you didn't setup frontend and backend, are you sure your haproxy serving you app ? and not something else ?

Comment: Add the frontend definition

Comment: Added the frontend  - is the renegotiation settings configured in the frontend? Is it not in the global config section?

Comment: And haproxy is functioning as a reverse proxy and terminating out TLS/SSL. So I figured that it would have the renegotiation settings rather then our backends which only sees plain text traffic.